# how to get result of getjson promise inside $.when function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

using the following code i try to get data of 2 getjson calls into array only when both getjson called completed. The code give me this error:

```
resultFromUrl1.feed is undefined
var entry1 = resultFromUr11.feed.entry;
```

i looked at f12 i saw both getjson executed successfully but no data get put into the array! how to fix this error ? furthermor should i use $.when(url1Promise, url2Promise).then or $.when(url1Promise, url2Promise).done ?

```
<javascript>
     var files = new Array();

        function pushtoArray() {

            //first getjson call
            var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json";
            var url1Promise = $.getJSON(url1, function (data) {
                console.log("url1 success");
            });//end of ajax call

            //second getjson call
            var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxxxx/xxxxx/public/values?alt=json";
            var url2Promise = $.getJSON(url2, function (data) {
                console.log("url2 success");
            });//end of function

            $.when(url1Promise, url2Promise).then(function (resultFromUrl1, resultFromUrl2) {
                var entry1 = resultFromUrl1.feed.entry;
                var entry2 = resultFromUrl2.feed.entry;

                var entry = entry1.concat(entry2);

                $(entry).each(function () {
                    // Column names are name, age, etc.
                    count++;
                    files.push({ url: this.gsx$url.$t, filename: this.gsx$name.$t });
                            alert(files.length);
                            print_r(files);
                            console.log(files);


                });


            });
        }//end of function 
            </javascript>
            <body onload="pushtoArray()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ajax functions are a bit of a pain to use with `$.when()`.  What is is in `resultFromURL1` is actually an array of three values like this: `[data, textStatus, jqXHR]`.

So, you need to change to:

```
var entry1 = resultFromUrl1[0].feed.entry;
var entry2 = resultFromUrl2[0].feed.entry;
```

---

In addition, you should add an error handler to your `$.when().then()` construct so you can see if any errors occurred in your `getJSON()` calls.

Comment: Thanks for reply . i get error as i posted above so i can't check the array result! both getjson tells me success on f12 window! the reason i use promise as it was suggest by some one in another post is to let both getjson finishes then i push data to array! But for some reason the $.when  function stops at every start complaing about resultFromUrl1.feed is undefined. How to fix this error ?

Comment: @user1788736 - OK, I see the issue now.  I've redone my answer.

Comment: thanks that fixed that error but keep getting this error this.gsx$url is undefined ! i want to get url and name element of getjson response if it successfully passed to $when function!

Comment: @user1788736 - When you get an error that something is `undefined`, you need to look for yourself at what the container is to see why the property is `undefined`.  Probably your data is different than you expect.  We don't know what your data is.  You have to see what it is.  So, add a `console.log(this)` inside your  `.each()` callback and see exactly what you have.  Or, even better, set a breakpoint in the debugger inside the `.each()` callback and step through the code examining variables as you go.  This is how you debug Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example using this url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/o13394135408524254648.240766968415752635/od6/public/values?alt=json"

It works fine..
You are receiving data. You can access the data by writing

```
resultFromUrl1[0].feed.entry
resultFromUrl2[0].feed.entry;
```